# Moving files via scheduled powershell script isn't working

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

A scheduled task calls an powershell script every 5 minutes. This script is moving xml files from one mounted network drive to another one. If the script is executed via the scheduled task the files don't get moved. If I execute the script manually via powershell ise the files got moved.

```
$source = 'D:\'
$target = '\\fileshare.domain.local\archive\'
$fname  = 'Example*.xml'

move-Item -Path $source$fname -Destination $target -passthru | foreach {$_.FullName}
```

The script is very simple and short.

The task is run as a service user, to which the drives are also mapped. The check boxes "run whether user is logged on or not" and "Run with  highest privileges" are both checked.
The action in the task looks like this:
Program/script:`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Add arguments (optional):`-file "E:\Copy-Script.ps1"`

E:\ is an separate drive where all my scripts are based.

I changed the settings of the scheduled task, but no matter what I changed the files have not been moved via the task.
I also thought that maybe the script doesn't get executed so I added logic to write a log file. The log file is written, but the files are not moved.

Comment: Not sure what settings you changed, but I guess the identity that the task runs under would be the one to focus on (since it will need to be an identity with access to the network share). Try changing `$target` to a path on the local machine to confirm this.

Comment: You are using Windows which means either you do not have permission to move the file (either source of destination) or the files are being used by another process.  I would check to see what account is being used to start the schedule task.

Comment: Monted network drive might not be available when run as task as mounting ist per user and sometimes also isoleted through UAC (User Account Control - "Run with highest privileges"). Use full path Like ```\\server.fqdn\share\``` instead

Comment: Does the log file capture error messages too (e.g., `... *>E:\log.txt`)? If so, do you see any errors?

Comment: Is this task scheduled to run on a laptop? also, check if there is a code/error code against the task.